# Como convertir un int en un char * en C

Tags: c

Basicamente necesito llamar a una funcion que requiere un char* como parametro y el dato, que cada vez tiene una longitud distinta, lo tengo en un int. ¿Como hago este cambio?

No puedo cambiar ninguna de las funciones

```
int valor = unafuncion();

int lafuncion(const char *name, const char *value);
```

Donde valor tiene que entrar por value.

Muchas gracias

Comment: La solución que buscas no está planteada en la pregunta, no puedes definir una 'Constante' cuando le pasas un valor diferente cada vez, ya que se convierte en una variable. Tu código y pregunta no son del todo claros, lo mejor sería que añadieras el código completo con una breve descripción de lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Lo que cambia cada vez es la variable int que tiene que ir dentro del puntero a constante, y que yo sepa si se puede cambiar el puntero señalando a un nuevo objeto. Lo que quiero hacer es pasar como parametro value de un setenv(const char*name, const char *value) lo obtenido por un getpid(). Se que se puede hacer metiendolo en un char * variable a traves de un snprintf que meto como parametro, pero necesito otra forma de hacerlo.